# Fusion Tables polygons colorfills based on merged table data

Tags: wordpress, rest, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

I need to create a new choropleth version of [this map](http://cmpf.eui.eu/mapping-media-policy-journalism/) whereby the polygons' colorFills respond to data in a column ("PERCENTAGE") from a table that I merged with the original fusion table. The polygons will be either green, yellow or red depending on the percentages.

I'm working from a wordpress plugin that was built by someone else for a project.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 51.41467424448992, 16.737563625000007 ),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // initialize the map
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ),
            myOptions );

    // google maps styles go below here...

    map.setOptions( { styles: styles } );

    // Initialize JSONP request
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?'];
    url.push( 'sql=' );
    var query = 'SELECT name, iso_a2, kml_4326 FROM ' +
            '1_XPSB5N6EOCr5i9etLrR0HA3717jfyk4iOamXWqu';
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent( query );
    url.push( encodedQuery );
    url.push( '&callback=drawMap' );
    url.push( '&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ' );
    script.src = url.join( '' );
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0];
    body.appendChild( script );
}

function drawMap( data ) {
    //console.log(getCountry);
    //console.log(data['rows']);
    var rows = data['rows'];
    for ( var i in rows ) {
        if ( rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica' ) {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var geometries = rows[i][2]['geometries'];
            if ( geometries ) {
                for ( var j in geometries ) {
                    newCoordinates.push( constructNewCoordinates( geometries[j] ) );
                }
            } else {
                newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates( rows[i][2]['geometry'] );
            }
            var fillColor = "#fff";
            var strokeColor = "transparent";//#333 ()

            if ( getCountry[rows[i][1]] ) {
                fillColor = "#fbbd2b";
                strokeColor = "#ff9900";
            }
            var country = new google.maps.Polygon( {
                paths: newCoordinates,
                strokeColor: strokeColor,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 0.4,
                fillColor: fillColor,
                fillOpacity: 0.18,
                name: getCountry[rows[i][1]],
                nameCode: rows[i][1]
            } );


            if ( getCountry[rows[i][1]] ) {
                google.maps.event.addListener( country, 'mouseover', function () {
                    this.setOptions( { fillOpacity: 0.4 } );
                } );
                google.maps.event.addListener( country, 'mouseout', function () {
                    this.setOptions( { fillOpacity: 0.18 } );
                } );
                google.maps.event.addListener( country, 'click', function () {
                    GetCounty( this.nameCode ); console.log(this.nameCode);
                } );
            }
            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.my_getBounds = function () {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                this.getPath().forEach( function ( element, index ) {
                    bounds.extend( element );
                } );
                return bounds;
            };
            var lat = country.my_getBounds().getCenter().lat();
            var lng = country.my_getBounds().getCenter().lng();
            country.setMap( map );
        }
    }
}

function constructNewCoordinates( polygon ) {
    var newCoordinates = [];
    var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
    for ( var i in coordinates ) {
        newCoordinates.push(
                new google.maps.LatLng( coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0] ) );
    }
    return newCoordinates;
}
    // Search form, contentpop code goes below here
```

I have tried adding the styles to the 'new google.maps.Polygon' variable (as below) but it didn't work so I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
    {
    where: 'PERCENTAGE < 33.3%',
       polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#0000FF'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'PERCENTAGE < 0.33' instead. The column is formatted as a percentage, but the actual value is a plain number. You can see this if you add a filter on that column.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Yes, you're right however there were some other issues. Will post answer below

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm still not sure why I couldn't get it working inside "var country new google.maps.Polygon" but managed it with "var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer"

```
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                select: 'iso_a2',
                from: '1_XPSB5N6EOCr5i9etLrR0HA3717jfyk4iOamXWqu'
                },
                    styles: [{
                    where: 'PERCENTAGE < 33.3',
                    polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: "#92bf24",
                    strokeColor: "#ff9900",
                } 
                }]
                });
                layer.setMap(map);
```

There will be 4 different maps in the dropdown though, so I might see if I can find a more convenient way to style the polygons - maybe from the SQL table, which is uncharted territory for me.